# Exclude multi-word keywords from Twitter Search API

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

I have a list of keywords to be excluded from search here

```
KEYWORDS = %w[
    covid corona subway railway travel plane brazil ]
```

`exclude = Twitter::KEYWORDS.split(",").join(" -")`

and this is how my search query looks like

```
 json_response = @client.search("(javascript) -#{exclude}", lang: "en", result_type: "recent", tweet_mode: "extended", count: 100)
```

How can I pass multi-word keywords here to be excluded, for example keywords like "off the hand" or "game plan"?

Adding them along with the other keywords doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Is you issue with storing multi-word arrays in a string, or passing them to Twitter? If you manually build the `@client.search` arguments to include multi-word strings, does that work?

Comment: Issue is with passing the multi-word arrays to Twitter. I tried building the argument like this @client.search("(javascript) -#{exclude} -"off the rails" ") but this doesn't work. @max-pleaner

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for how these search queries are built? They specifically mention that multi-word exclusion should be handled word-by-word, e.g. `-off -the -rails` https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/recent-search/guides/search-queries

Comment: To clarify, the Twitter Ruby gem is using the old search https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets rather than the one in labs, but yes, you would still have to negate each term individually.

Comment: Thanks! I did take a look at Twitter docs. But what if I have to exclude the exact match ```"off the rails"``` ? If I build it like `-off` `-the` `-rails` then it would also exclude the tweets where any of these words are present. I only want to exclude the tweets if it is an exact match of the keyword `"off the rails"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes back looking for the same problem, this is how I solved it:

```
@client.search("(javascript) -#{exclude} -\"off the hand\" -\"game plan\", lang: "en", result_type: "recent", tweet_mode: "extended", count: 100)
```

So, basically by using escape characters which allowed me to pass multi-word keywords as an exact string.